# Very strange bug when using data binding to element under a Telerik RadTreeView

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, telerik

I have the following XAML code as part of a custom control:

```
<telerik:RadTreeView x:Name="treeModules"> 
    <telerik:RadTreeView.ItemTemplate> 
        <core:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Submodules}"> 
            <local:ModuleInfoUserControl IsReadOnly="{Binding ElementName=ctrlIsReadOnly, Path=IsReadOnly}"/> 
        </core:HierarchicalDataTemplate> 
    </telerik:RadTreeView.ItemTemplate> 
</telerik:RadTreeView>
```

Where:

- The `ItemsSource` property of
  `treeModules` is set by code to a list
  of `Module` objects. The `Module` class
  has a property named `Submodules`,
  which consists on a collection of
  more Modules.
- `ModuleInfoUserControl` is a custom
  control used to display module
  information. `IsReadOnly` is a
  dependency property declared on the
  control.
- `ctrlIsReadOnly` is a hidden TextBox
  defined elsewhere in the main user
  control. It is used to make a bunch
  of controls editable or read only.

**The problem:** binding to `ctrlIsReadOnly` element in `ModuleInfoUserControl` does not work. The `IsReadOnly` property of it is always at its default state, even if the corresponding property of `crlIsReadOnly` changes.

**But**, if I change the RadTreeView into a standard Silverlight TreeView, and the HierarchicalDataTemplate into the standard Silverlight version too, it works as expected.

---

Ok, up to here I have pasted an exact copy of the support ticket I have sent to Telerik in the hope that they could help me. I must say that the reply has been quick and as efficient as it could be: they have said me that they could not reproduce the bug, and have send me a small test project that exercises the offending piece of code. The test project shows the bug on my machine, but works on Telerik's.

And here comes the really strange part. I have published Telerik's sample project on my personal site. Here is the link:

http://www.konamiman.com/TelerikTest/TestPage.html

The idea is that when pressing the "ToggleIsReadOnly" button, the "Root" TextBox should become read-only. But again, it works on Telerik's machines, but not on mine! So the application code itself is apparenly ok.

Thinking that it could be a problem on my machine's Silverlight runtime, I have tested a bunch of others, including: Spanish Windows 7 32 and 64 bits, Spanish Windows XP, English Windows Server 2008, and even on my wife's computer with Japanese Windows XP. **On all of these, it does NOT work as expected**.

So, what's happening here? I am completely stuck.

By the way, Silverlight Runtime I'm using is version 3.0.50106.0.

**UPDATE:** I have uploaded the source code of the test project as well. Here is the URL:

http://www.konamiman.com/TelerikTest/TreeViewTest.zip

Comment: Does not work for me either. ctrlIsReadOnly *does* switch to readonly, but not the "Root" textbox.

Comment: Please upload the source code for the Telerik sample project somewhere, and I will give it a go.

Comment: Thank you, please see the updated question for the URL. So you are from Sweden? I wonder if the problem is with non-English client machines then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an alternative approach that seems to work fine. Instead of defining `ctrlIsReadOnly` as part of the main user control tree, I define it as a static resource:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <TextBox x:Key="ctrlIsReadOnly" IsEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="False" Visibility="Collapsed" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then I just have to slightly change the binding declaration on ModuleInfoUserControl:

```
<local:ModuleInfoUserControl IsReadOnly="{Binding Source={StaticResource ctrlIsReadOnly}, Path=IsReadOnly}"/>
```

I then access ctrlIsReadOnly from code this way: `((TextBox)this.Resources["ctrlIsReadOnly"])`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the test project now, and I can not get it to work. I have tried changing the thread culture to "en-US", but that does not help. It would appear that items controls a HierarchicalDataTemplate cannot bind to properties on elements *outside* of that datatemplate. I think you should get back to Telerik and ask them again if they are 100% sure that this works as expected on their machines. If it does, it is a very strange bug.

**[EDIT]**
I have found some more info, see the links below. It looks like this is a general silverlight problem. But it is still strange that the Telerik guy claims that it works on his machine.
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/108804/267789.aspx

And here is a similar thing but with the Telerik GridView component:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/gridview/elementname-binding-inside-of-celltemplate.aspx

Comment: Also, it is worth noting that with the standard Silverlight TreeView and HierarchicalDataTemplate, it works fine...

Comment: Ok. Interesting... That means it is definitely Teleriks problem. You should post this bug to them again. Maybe they just misunderstood the bug the first time around.